# Algorithm to detect sawtooth like timeSeries

Tags: algorithm, time, statistics, computation

**What you see here is a Graph of acceleration on the Vertical Axis (or head to toe axis) of a person walking.**

[image]

I want to Implement a reliable method to recognise this pattern of motion and count no of steps.

As we can immediately notice each step corresponds to a spike and dip from the mean around 10-10.5 ms^2 line.

Earlier I planned on a Threshold detection based mechanism but that yielded very poor results because there are some variables:

1. If the person walks slower or faster the graph would expand out in time axis
2. If a person steps lighter or harder then the spikes and dips are smaller and larger respectively

however in all of  the cases the pattern is still the same that is a spike and dip at almost regular intervals

what is the best reasonable algorithm to detect this pattern with reasonable accuracy and computing time

Comment: Consider asking on http://dsp.stackexchange.com if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: I'd start with a peak detector.

Comment: I'd start with an FFT of the autocorrelation function to obtain a power spectrum, then find the peak. Almost certainly the frequency of the peak will be what you want. Comparing the peak to the average power will give you a good estimate of the peak's reliability.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I figured it out, it was rather very simple ,all I had to do was decide a noise threshold and a base level or zero level then run a peak detector on it

**following is the abstract procedure**

- Base level is calculated in Real time as average of last 30 samples
- Values above base level - noise threshold were considered as positive spikes
- Values below base level - noise threshold were considered as negative spikes
- A pair of subsequent positive and negative spikes detected within a short interval of about ~500ms is considered as step.

with proper tuning the accuracy is **~98%** and can count no of steps taken very reliably